# Ember.js - Controller not picking model data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-model, ember-controllers

I have a model which has this field

```
diaryItemLabel: DS.attr('string'),
```

I want to access the data from this field in my controller.

```
Controller.js
```

[image]

I want to replace the *'Add'* with whatever data I get from *diaryItemLabel*.

I cannot use *this.get('model.diaryItemLabel')*. It gives me this.get() is not a function.
I tried using *Ember.get('model', 'diaryItemLabel')*. It gives me empty string.

Edit 1: Set default to 'Add' if *model.diaryItemLabel* variable is empty.

Could someone guide me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller will get `model` property only after `setupController` hook which will be called after `model` hook.

Create computed property which dependant on `model.diaryItemLabel` in controller which will return your required object

```
confirm:Ember.computed('model.diaryItemLabel',function(){
 let temp = {};
 temp.accept= { text: Ember.isEmpty(this.get('model.diaryItemLabel')) ? 'Add' : this.get('model.diaryItemLabel'), buttonClass: 'btn btn-primary'};
 temp.reject = { text: 'cancel', buttonClass: 'btn btn-default'};
 return temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kumkanillam

Comment: Also can you tell me how do I set the temp.accept text default to 'Add'. So if model.diaryItemLabel is empty, then set it to 'Add'

Comment: Updated answer with isEmpty check . http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_isEmpty

Comment: I think your Edit is better than mine, so I will let it be. Thanks for your time and effort